Is it possible to calculate date and change the amount with script when it is memorized transaction? in netsuite
I created a transaction where I run a script which check it the hire date is more then 455 days. If yes it will calculate the amount, if no then it will show 0. Then I am using memorized transaction to repeat the transaction every day. In next transaction all of the hire date is more then 455 days but the amount is showing still 0 as before. Is it possible to calculate date and change the amount when it is memorized transaction?
Script is working when the transaction is created but amount is not automatically changing for memorized transaction.

clientscript:
define(['N/record','N/search','N/ui/dialog','N/runtime', 'N/log'], function (record,runtime, search, dialog, log) {

/**

*@NApiVersion 2.0

*@NScriptType ClientScript

*/

function fieldChanged(context) {

var currentRecord = context.currentRecord;

var field2Value = currentRecord.getCurrentSublistValue({

sublistId: 'line',

fieldId: 'custcol_ih_lempsalary'

});

var field3Value = currentRecord.getCurrentSublistValue({

sublistId: 'line',

fieldId: 'custcol_ih_pfpercent'

});

var field4Value = currentRecord.getCurrentSublistValue({

sublistId: 'line',

fieldId: 'custcol_ih_pfeligible'

});

var field5Value = currentRecord.getCurrentSublistValue({

sublistId: 'line',

fieldId: 'custcol_ih_pfhired'

});

try {

var todaydate = new Date();

// var dat1 = Date.parse(field5Value);

const firstDate = new Date(field5Value); // 10th May, 2022

const secondDate = new Date(); // today, 14th May, 2022

const firstDateInMs = firstDate.getTime();

const secondDateInMs = secondDate.getTime();

const differenceBtwDates = secondDateInMs - firstDateInMs;

const aDayInMs = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;

const daysDiff = Math.round(differenceBtwDates / aDayInMs);

if (daysDiff>=456){

if(context.sublistId == 'line' && context.fieldId == 'custcol_ih_lempsalary' && 'custcol_ih_pfpercent' && 'custcol_ih_pfhired'){

currentRecord.setCurrentSublistValue({

sublistId: 'line',

fieldId: 'amount',

value: (field2Value * (field3Value/100)) * 2,

}); } }

else{

if(context.sublistId == 'line' && context.fieldId == 'custcol_ih_lempsalary' && 'custcol_ih_pfpercent' && 'custcol_ih_pfhired'){

currentRecord.setCurrentSublistValue({

sublistId: 'line',

fieldId: 'amount',

value: 0.00001,

}); }

} } catch (e) {

// this ternary operator will catch all the ns errors. you can fail silently here

var error = 'PLEASE CHECK EMPLOYEE SALARY & HIRE DATE';

throw error; }

}

return {

fieldChanged: fieldChanged

};

})


No need to modify the memorized transaction. Update/add what is needed in the transaction when it is created from the memorized transaction.
